# Confused on AND bit masking

Tags: c, gcc, bit-manipulation

I am playing around with bit masking and I had thought I understood bitwise math...apparently not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%08x", 0x01111111 & 0xF0F0F0F);

    /* 
     * 0000 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 
     * 1111 0000 1111 0000 1111 0000 1111 
     * -----------------------------
     * 0000 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 
     */ 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Above is a code snippet of a simple bit mask using `F0F0F0F` to turn off every other byte.

I know that `0111 1111` converted to binary is `0000 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001`. If we AND mask this against `1111 0000 1111 0000 1111 0000 1111` I would expected the output to be `0000 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001`. However running this program gives a result I didn't expect - `01010101`. It would appear the leading 0 in the MSB position is disregarded?

I'm sorry if this is trivial, I'm sure it is. But I am confused by this as I am not sure how this result is given.

Comment: You've aligned the numbers to the left rather than right. As an analogy, 10 + 1 is 11, not 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0xF0F0F0F` is really `0x0F0F0F0F`. When you don't type "enough" digits to fill the whole integer, zeros are inserted automatically (e.g. if you just type 0x1, the internal representation is 0x00000001 for 32 bit integers).

So for your code it's

```
/* 
 * 0000 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 (binary)
 * 0000 1111 0000 1111 0000 1111 0000 1111 (binary) 
 * ---------------------------------------
 * 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001  (binary)
 */
```

and when printed as hex, you get `01010101`

Comment: I see so zeroes are added to the front as padding, not the back. Not sure why I didn't realize this sooner. Thanks!

Comment: @CL40 Correct... but... don't call it padding. The zeros are part of the number. Inside the processor `int`s have fixed size (32 bit in your case) so the zeros are not padding but part of the number

Comment: it's just like in decimal where 00001, 001 and 1 are exactly the same thing. Leading zeros have no significant value

Answer (score 0):

This is what's happening:

```
    /* 
     * 0000 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 
     * 0000 1111 0000 1111 0000 1111 0000 1111 
     * -----------------------------
     * 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 
     */
```

`0xF0F0F0F` has 0's at the beginning. That's what `0x` means. So for, 0x1, 1 is the least significant bit.